# Django admin can't create records for model with self-referential foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

This is my model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    referee = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I try to create a customer via admin site I got this error:

```
TypeError at /admin/customer/customer/add/
Field 'id' expected a number but got <Customer: my_customer_name>.
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Dont' know  & this other issue seems far too old https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1839 ... Maybe try to add a related_name argument in ForeignKey.

Comment: @franckfournier that's not my problem bro. The exception is different. In my case, when I create new customer on admin site I got the type error: the field referee expected a number( the id of an existing customer) but it got the name because of ```__str__``` method. If the field refer to another model, there's no problem with ```__str__```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this error. This is not caused by the model or the admin but by a custom model method I made. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: no pb. happy you sole the issue